# Error in laravel5.2: Method groups does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working on laravel 5.2.I want to display those members who belongs to that particular group which is open at this time. Actually, i am getting all the members which i have stored in my database but, i only want to access or display only those members who belongs to a particular on which i am currently accessing. I am getting an error: Method groups does not exist. which is shown below:[image][image]

My controller:

```
     public function members($id){
     $dashes=Grouptable::findorFail($id);
     $members=Member::all();
     return view('members' , ['dashes'=>$dashes,'members'=>$members]);

     }

     public function dashboard($id){
     $dashes=Grouptable::findorFail($id);
     return view('dashboard' , ['dashes'=>$dashes]);

     }
     public function addmembers(Request $request){
     $member=new Member();
     $member->members=$request['addmember'];
     $request->groups()->members()->save($member);

     return redirect()->back();
     }
```

My view:

```
      <body>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
      <img src="images/ImgResponsive_Placeholder.png" 
      class="img-circle img-  responsive" alt="Placeholder image"> </div>
     <div class="col-lg-7">
     <h1 style="color:black;">{{ $dashes->name }}</h1></div>
        <br />
     </div>
      <div class="row">

     <div class="col-lg-3">

      <button class="btn btn-success"  onclick="myFunction()">
       Add Members +   </button>
       <div>

     <form id="demo" style="display:none;" method="post"
      action="{{ route('addmember') }}">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="addmember">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
     </form>

         </div>
          </div>

        <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-0">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div  id="grp" class="panel-heading">
         <h3 id="grouptitle" class="panel-title">Group Members</h3>
       </div>
         <div  id="zx" class="panel-content">
         <div class="row">
          @foreach($members as $member)
          <section class="col-md-6">

          <div class="row">

          <section class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 col-xs-offset-1
           col-xs-4">
         <img id="imagesize" src="images/g.jpg" class="img-circle"/>
         </section>
         <section class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-7 col-xs-7">
          <section class="col-md-12">

           <h5 id="friendname">{{$member->members}}</h5>

           </section>

             </section>
              </div>
              </section>
             </div>

              </section>
              @endforeach

         </div>
          <div id="mn" class="panel-footer"><a id="seemr1"
          href="#.html">See More</a></div>
           </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
             </div>
             </div>
            </div>
            </body>
```

My routes:

```
             Route::get('/members/{id}',[
             'uses'=>'GroupController@members',
             'as'=>'members'
              ]);
              Route::get('/dashboard/{id}',[
              'uses'=>'GroupController@dashboard',
             'as'=>'dashboard'
               ]);
                Route::post('/member/add',[
               'uses'=>'GroupController@addmembers',
               'as'=>'addmember'
               ]);
```

My modals:

```
                Grouptable:
                public function members(){
                  return $this->hasMany('App\Member');
                 }

               Member:

                  public function groups(){
                  return $this->hasMany('App\Grouptable');
                    }
```

Comment: You have to try with statement of laravel. Like $users = Role::with('users')->where('name', 'agent')->get()->toArray();

Comment: can you please tell in detail?

Comment: Where does method groups() on $request come from within your controller function addmembers()? This is an Illuminate\Http\Request object right?

Comment: groups() function is in my modal. i use it in my relationship here

Comment: But you called it on $request object, maybe a typo?

Comment: actually, i am trying to add the request member into a particular group using this relationship here

Comment: i have already provide you my modals, you can check them too

Comment: You double check your code in your controller method addmembers(). You didn't call groups() on your Member object but on Laravel's Illuminate\Http\Request object. Of course it does not exist. That's my argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120566/discussion-between-vivek-titwal-and-carter).